About semi-direct product of two cyclic groups
The following question is related to seeing semi-direct products as subgroups:
Let $G$ be a non-nilpotent group and $U = \langle x \rangle$ be a cyclic characteristic subgroup of the Fitting subgroup ${\mathrm{Fit}}(G)$ (which is the largest normal nilpotent subgroup of $G$). Let $y \in G \setminus {\mathrm{Fit}}(G)$ be an element of prime order $q$. Suppose that the product $K := \langle y \rangle \cdot \langle x \rangle$ is  non-abelian. My question is: under what conditions one can find all element of $K \setminus \langle x \rangle$ are of order $q$ ?
It is easy to see that any element of $K$ outside $\langle x \rangle$ has order divisible by $q$. Secondly, this would always be the case when $q=2$ (which forces $K$ to be dihedral of order $2|U|$).

Many of your statements are wrong. The fact that $y \not\in {\rm Fit}(G)$ does not guarantee that $\langle x,y \rangle \ne \langle x \rangle \times \langle y \rangle$. On the other hand, the fact that $\langle x \rangle$ is normal in ${\rm Fit}(G)$ does not guarantee that $y$ normalizes $\langle x \rangle$. And even if it does with $q=2$, this does not force $K$ to be dihedral.

@Derek: I understand that $y \not\in {\mathrm{Fit}}(G)$ does not gurantee that the product non-abelian. This is what I obtained from certain recipe. So, I will revise the question. But once that is done, Fitting subgroup being characteristic and $U$ normal inside it, shouldn't imply that $y$ normalize $\langle x \rangle$?

No, for example in the group $G=A_4$, we have $|{\rm Fit}(G)| = 4$. Let $x = (1,2)(3,4)$. Then $\langle x \rangle$ is normal in ${\rm Fit}(G)$ but not in $A_4$, and it is not normalized by $y=(2,3,4)$. In general $H$ characteristic in $K$ and $K$ normal in $G$ imply $H$ is normal in $G$, but not the other way round.

@Derek: I nearly forgot that the cyclic group $U = \langle x \rangle$ I considered was the unique subgroup of order $|x|$ in $G$, to be starting with. This forces $\langle x \rangle$ is characteristic inside $G$ as well, and also force $\langle x \rangle \leq {\mathrm{Fit}}(G)$. However, let me weaken it just by putting $\langle x \rangle$ is characteristic inside ${\mathrm{Fit}}(G)$. My apologies for the confusion.
